# openapi-generator-cli couldn't list installed versions

Tags: openapi-generator-cli

I tried to install openapi-generator-cli using following command.
`npm install @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli -g` and tried to list installed versions with `openapi-generator-cli version-manager list`. It throws an error as:

```
Error
    at C:\Users\rk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@openapitools\openapi-generator-cli\main.js:2:27016
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:430:5)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1098:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:450:11)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:350:12)
```

Node version: v18.19.0, openapi-generator-cli: 7.2.0, Windows

I had tried installing different version of openapi-generator-cli but it didn't work. It was working fine on version 6.4.0, all of a sudden it stopped working.

Comment: I'd suggest opening an issue in the project's issue tracker https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator-cli/issues

Comment: thanks @Helen, created the issue on the repo: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator-cli/issues/753